# Library for time-series data

Tags: time-series

I'm looking for an open-source library in perl, python or even LISP for handling time-series data. The data will be read in from CSV files: data run lengths will typically be every 10 mins for two years. Can anyone recommend a library that would allow me load the data into an object and to for example, 'exclude all Sundays between 13:00 and 19:00' from the dataset, or conveniently create an object with all the periods I want excluded and to a AND operation on the original dataset. Must be able to handle more than a set of values per time sample.

I've seen pandas for python, it looks promising, any others come to mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas is certainly one good way to go.  R language also has good support for timeseries.

```
from pandas import Series, date_range
from numpy.random import randn
rng = date_range('1/1/2011', periods=10000, freq='10min')
ts = Series(randn(len(rng)), index=rng)

filtered_index = rng[((rng.dayofweek!=6) | ((rng.hour < 13) | (rng.hour>=19)))]
no_sunday_afternoons = ts[filtered_index]
print no_sunday_afternoons['2011-01-02 12:30:00':'2011-01-02 19:30:00']


2011-01-02 12:30:00   -1.395918
2011-01-02 12:40:00    0.382604
2011-01-02 12:50:00   -0.422495
2011-01-02 19:00:00   -0.341497
2011-01-02 19:10:00    0.982950
2011-01-02 19:20:00   -0.909796
2011-01-02 19:30:00    0.842446
dtype: float64
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was after. Thanks for taking the time to write an example.